# Why did Taft write a one cent check on his first day as Chief Justice?

Tags: united-states, president

I was looking at [William Howard Taft's Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Howard_Taft), and among other things was a $0.01 check drafted by him on his first day as Chief Justice of the United States.

The check has ended up at the Smithsonian, but is there some deeper story behind it? It appears to be made out to Naldo(?) C Moore?

[image: One cent check drafted by Taft]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The name is Waldo C. Moore. [This page](http://famous-celebrity-autographs.com/waldo-moore-passionate-check-collector-a-176.html) says that he was a check collector:

> Moore sent famous people a request for an autographed bank check for one cent that was accompanied by his signed one-cent bearer note drawn on The Peoples Banking Company, Lewisburg, Ohio.  Moore sent this request to hundreds of celebrities and his appeal received a surprisingly large number of affirmative replies.